# Auto create file from template and use external file with user data

Tags: notepad++, csv, mail-merge

I would like to ask if somebody knows a way to auto-create files (save as .txt) from a template that substitutes data (maybe placeholders?) from external file.

I will try to explain an example.

I have one template with the folowing in one file for example named "service_template.txt":

> Service-Note, Parcel from customer AAA needs to be pickup on station
>   BBB. Please inform station BBB to prepare and only provide the parcel
>   to AAA with userid identification.
>
> Kind regards

Now, I have a file with content that needs to be replaced on AAA and BBB named as example "userstations.csv". The file with the content is a csv file that is everytime updated. It looks like this:

```
"Hans","BOM2356734CH"
"John","ER345634656UK"
"Peter","VA523526672DE"
```

For every line user, it creates a file from the template avobe filed with the information AAA and BBB from the csv file and saves it auto with the name of the person, in this case AAA.txt

Completed it looks like this for the first person Hans.txt:

> Service-Note, Parcel from customer Hans needs to be pickup on station
>   BOM2356734CH. Please inform station BOM2356734CH to prepare and only
>   provide the parcel to Hans with userid identification.
>
> Kind regards

At the moment I do hardwork for over 200 users with notepad++ and function find & replace and save it manually with the persons name which is extremely time consuming and not really productive.

I am open to use other tools or methods if someone has a idea how to automate this process or even in php whatever.

Thanks a lot for all in advance :)

Comment: What you're looking for is called mail merge, you can set it up and use e.g. in Microsoft Word (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-create-and-send-bulk-mail-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705), or any other alternatives (open office...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Máté, the problem is that for each separate user needs to be create a file with the name and saved as txt. No mails are sent like in mail merge. At the end i need to upload all theses txt files at once to the server, otherwise i think the sistem does not recognize it.

Comment: Mail merge doesn't mean you need to send mails. It certainly has the functionality to save all dataset into separate file, I'm not sure it can be also .txt, but even if MS word can't, you may still check its alternatives.

Comment: Nope, is not what i am looking for. It only saves all in one file and has not the ability to save all individual with their names like AAA -> Hans.txt from the database. Openoffice is also unable to do it. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution with the sistem Máté proposed. If someone need it in the future.

If you are using Word XP or later, the “Add-in to Merge Letters to Separate Files” on which Graham has collaborated and that can be downloaded from the site: http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm and allows you to create each letter as a separate file with a filename taken from a field in the data source with a minimum of fuss.

Hope this also helps someone in the future :)

Cheers... Geniexo